# Click event on stacked bar chart - ChartJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js, stacked-chart

I am trying to implement click event on Stacked Bar chart.

**The data looks like below:**

```
var chartData = {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ['A0224', 'A3681', 'A3984', 'A4101', 'A4150', 'B0682', 'Others'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "P1",
                backgroundColor: '#cc3399',
                data: [6, 7, 6, 8, 6, 10, 3]
            },
            {
                label: "P2",
                backgroundColor: '#0099ff',
                data: [8, 9, 5, 8, 6, 10, 3]
            },
            {
                label: "P3",
                backgroundColor: '#0022ff',
                data: [6, 7, 6, 8, 6, 10, 3]
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        legend: { display: false },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        },

    }
}
```

**The method for click event and chart creation looks like below:**

```
var myChart = new
    Chart(document.getElementById("createCurrYearHccGapChart"),
    chartData);
var canvas = document.getElementById('createCurrYearHccGapChart');
canvas.onclick = function (evt) {
    var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
    var cdata = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
    var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];
    var label = cdata.datasets[idx].label;
    var value = cdata.datasets[0].data[idx];
};
```

**And the chart looks like below :**

[image: Stacked bar chart]

**Below are the values i am getting wherever i click on single bar:**
Bar 1 - label = P1, value = 6 
Bar 2 - label = P2, value = 7 
Bar 3 - label = P3, value = 6 and etc...

**Problem:** 
 So wherever i click on the 1st bar the label is P1 its because i am getting the index value as 0 for the entire bar and 1 for bar 2 and so on.

**Question:**
Is there any way to identify the x coordinate value? so that i can identify the click is from which stack.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could accomplish this using the following *on-click* event handler for your chart ...

```
canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
   var activePoint = myChart.getElementAtEvent(evt)[0];
   var data = activePoint._chart.data;
   var datasetIndex = activePoint._datasetIndex;
   var label = data.datasets[datasetIndex].label;
   var value = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[activePoint._index];
};
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var chartData = {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: {
      labels: ['A0224', 'A3681', 'A3984', 'A4101', 'A4150', 'B0682', 'Others'],
      datasets: [{
         label: "P1",
         backgroundColor: '#cc3399',
         data: [6, 7, 6, 8, 6, 10, 3]
      }, {
         label: "P2",
         backgroundColor: '#0099ff',
         data: [8, 9, 5, 8, 6, 10, 3]
      }, {
         label: "P3",
         backgroundColor: '#0022ff',
         data: [6, 7, 6, 8, 6, 10, 3]
      }]
   },
   options: {
      responsive: false,
      legend: {
         display: false
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            stacked: true
         }],
         xAxes: [{
            stacked: true
         }]
      },

   }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('createCurrYearHccGapChart');
var myChart = new Chart(canvas, chartData);

canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
   var activePoint = myChart.getElementAtEvent(evt)[0];
   var data = activePoint._chart.data;
   var datasetIndex = activePoint._datasetIndex;
   var label = data.datasets[datasetIndex].label;
   var value = data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[activePoint._index];
   console.log(label, value);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="createCurrYearHccGapChart" height="170"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked like charm :)
More over it requires latest version of chartjs for **getElementAtEvent** method.

Comment: Hi @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ, I used this solution as it is, but I'm getting zero for activePoint._datasetIndex , no matter on which bar I click. DO you have any idea about it? Thanks.

Comment: Totally works, make sure "myChart" and other variables are consistent across the code. It allows for clicking on a specific chunk of the graph, and returning it's label and value attributes.

Comment: You could use `this` instead of named chart. It will be more generic.
This has worked for me: `var activePoint = this.getElementAtEvent(event)[0];`

Comment: can i do same with react native svg charts

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of Chart.js, the below code would work.

```
const ctx = $('#monitor');
monitorChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

ctx.on('click', function(evt) {
  const points = monitorChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);

  if (points.length) {
    const firstPoint = points[0];
    const label = monitorChart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
    const slabel = monitorChart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].label;
    const value = monitorChart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].data[firstPoint.index];
    console.log(label, slabel, value);
  }
});
```

You can check [Here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementsateventformode-e-mode-options-usefinalposition)!